# 2 rows in header

Tags: android, header, screen, android-actionbar

I can do a header and a spinner NEAR the header in action bar, but

-1. How can I do this - 2 rows in header (Inbox) and a spinner (xyz.xyz@android.com):

[image]

-2. near the header there is a place, but the buttons are in the bottom of the screen. If I do in xml "IfRoom" android decides which button will be near the header and which one in the bottom.

-3. and this - 2 rows and a font in header(THUESDAY, JUNE 21)

[image]

Comment: why are you mixing ActionBar with Notification?

Comment: ok, just do not pay attancion to 3.